# adding maven repository for expect dependency with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle, classpath

I've tried a few variations on the `implementation` syntax which I believe is incorrect below.  I'm not quite sure that I have the correct repository for this dependency, either.

running gradle:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ gradle clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 769ms
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ gradle clean build

> Task :compileJava
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:4: error: package net.sf.expectit.matcher does not exist
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.contains;
                                     ^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:4: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.contains;
^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:5: error: package net.sf.expectit.matcher does not exist
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.eof;
                                     ^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:5: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.eof;
^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:6: error: package net.sf.expectit.matcher does not exist
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.regexp;
                                     ^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:6: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.regexp;
^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
        ^
  symbol:   class Expect
  location: class App
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
                            ^
  symbol:   class ExpectBuilder
  location: class App
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        expect.expect(contains("Press Return to continue"));
                      ^
  symbol:   method contains(String)
  location: class App
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        expect.expect(contains("forecast city code--"));
                      ^
  symbol:   method contains(String)
  location: class App
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/expect/src/main/java/expect/App.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        expect.expect(contains("X to exit:"));
                      ^
  symbol:   method contains(String)
  location: class App
11 errors

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.7 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.7+10)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-29-generic amd64

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/expect$
```

code:

```
package expect;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.contains;
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.eof;
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.regexp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class App {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().telnet();
    }

    private void telnet() {
        log.info("foo");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com");

        StringBuilder wholeBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
                .withOutput(process.getOutputStream())
                .withInputs(process.getInputStream())
                .withEchoOutput(wholeBuffer)
                .withEchoInput(wholeBuffer)
                .withExceptionOnFailure()
                .build();

        expect.expect(contains("Press Return to continue"));
        expect.sendLine();
        expect.expect(contains("forecast city code--"));
        expect.sendLine("SAN");
        expect.expect(contains("X to exit:"));
        expect.sendLine();

        String response = wholeBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println(response);

        expect.close();

    }

}
```

build file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use TestNG framework, also requires calling test.useTestNG() below
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.0.0'  


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.expectit/expectit-core
//    implementation 'net.sf.expectit' name 'expectit-core', version '0.9.0'
//    implementation 'net.sf.expectit' name: 'expectit-core', version: '0.9.0'


}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = 'expect.App'
}

test {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}
```

Comment: try `mavenCentral()` repository

Comment: Yeah, no luck with that.  I'm trying to clear the cache, see that it downloads, etc.  I think that's probably the problem, though -- something like that.

Comment: What is your gradle version? Also can you try using `implementation` instead of `compile`

Comment: I updated the question, @smac89 and am looking at `implementation`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. I just tried your code and without `mavenCentral()` repo, it works for me. I used `implementation 'net.sf.expectit:expectit-core:0.9.0'`

Comment: thanks @smac89 got it at least running..see below.

Answer (score 1):

runs:

```
package expectit;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.contains;
import static net.sf.expectit.matcher.Matchers.eof;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class App {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new App().telnet();
    }

    private void telnet() throws IOException {
        log.info("foo");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com");

        StringBuilder wholeBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        net.sf.expectit.Expect expect = new net.sf.expectit.ExpectBuilder()
                .withOutput(process.getOutputStream())
                .withInputs(process.getInputStream())
                .withEchoOutput(wholeBuffer)
                .withEchoInput(wholeBuffer)
                .withExceptionOnFailure()
                .build();

        expect.expect(contains("Press Return to continue"));
        expect.sendLine();
        expect.expect(contains("forecast city code--"));
        expect.sendLine("SAN");
        expect.expect(contains("X to exit:"));
        expect.sendLine();

        String response = wholeBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println(response);

        expect.close();

    }

}
```

https://github.com/THUFIR/expectit

thanks smac89

Comment: Glad it's working for you now. If you did anything special to make it work, don't forget to include that in your answer

Comment: rather than using an import statement I used the fully qualified class and interface names as above...but I think that had more with using gradle 6 when NB works with gradle 5.  Otherwise, dunno.